# How to avoid rerender in Intertia after post?

Tags: laravel, inertiajs

In my Laravel/Vue app I hav a page to show all tickets:

```
public function index(): Response
{
    $tickets = Tickets::all();
    return Inertia::render('Dashboard/Issues/Index', compact('tickets'));
}
```

On the front end that displays all tickets, I have a method to add a new ticket:

```
const addTicket = () => {
    Inertia.post('/dashboard/ticket, ticket);
    tickets.push(ticket);
}
```

In my controller, the endpoint to create a ticket looks like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->ticketCreator->create($request->all());
}
```

It seems that making the post request reloads my entire page. So it seems like a GET request is made to get all the content. How is this possible? And how can I avoid this?

[image]

I don't want that the page is re-rendered behind the scenes, because I already took care of updating my data using

```
tickets.push(ticket);
```

Answer (score 0):

when using Inertia::class you need to provide a return, in this case after

```
$this->ticketCreator->create($request->all());
```

you need to do:

```
return Redirect::route('Dashboard/Issues/Index');
```

So the reactive method of Inertia will reload the component and will show the new ticket created automatically, so no need to do tickets.push(ticket)
Code will be:

```
$this->ticketCreator->create($request->all());
return Redirect::route('Dashboard/Issues/Index');
```

Comment: It seems that the redirect is not needed. As you can see on my network tab, its redirecting, although I have a void controller method. I see that the component is reloaded, but I want to prevent that actually, as I think its quicker for me to add a comment, then to reload 1000 tickets.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer is, if you want to prevent reload, simply use axios instead of Intertia helper.